# Android: what does "setTextFilterEnabled" method do?

Tags: java, android, listview

What does the **setTextFilterEnabled()** method do?

Comment: Please learn to use the Android Developer Resource
http://developer.android.com/intl/en/reference/packages.html

You can search the index.

Comment: Within an hour, this question was the #1 Google hit for setTextFilterEnabled. Scary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It basically enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView.  However, the caveat, as explained [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/22b015b031a13bb2) is that the filtering doesn't happen automatically.  According to that link, you have to provide the filtering logic and then according to the AbsListView docs that outline that method, the adapter you call that method on must also implement [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html).

Hope that helps...

Comment: The statement that the filtering doesn't happen automatically is misleading. The referred topic only says that for SimpleCursorAdapter. ArrayAdapter will get filtered using the toString() method, eg. ArrayAdapter<MyClass> will get filtered basing on MyClass.toString(). No other code needs to be written.

Answer (score 10):

According to the Android Developer Reference, the setTextFilterEnabled() method "enables or disables the type filter window. If enabled, typing when this view has focus will filter the children to match the users input."

Source and extra information can be found at the Android Developer Reference, ie : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setTextFilterEnabled%28boolean%29

Answer (score 3):

It is used for filtering the contents of the given ListView .when you type a letter then you will be automatically scrolled to that item if it is there in  that view .